# Data transformations and Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, bigdata

I have a rather architectural question concerning logstash.

We have logfiles produced by hardware devices which are very cryptic. Some kind of transformation and enhancing has to happen before sending the JSON to elasticsearch. Eg I get arrays of numbers which should get transformed to something readable. Some kind of enum value transformation.

Things can get even more complicated on doing these transformations. Eg having a config file for each device which has to be taken in concern on doing the transformations.

Now IMO there are 3 opinions to achieve this:

- use the logstash-filter-mutate plugin
- implement my own logstash-filter plugin
- use logstash as a small webserver and do the transformations upfront

Do you have any experiences on those ways? What would you prefer and why?

BW Hubert

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I agree with you. You will manipulate your data with something(logstash filters, beat, ...) and forward to somewhere (elasticsearch or another logstash).

In my opinion, logstash is too heavy for a production server. We used before and it uses too many resources. Elasticsearch has Beats to handle this. (I know it is not about only this situation.) You can just use [beats](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats) to collect logs from file. In your case, there is a extreme issue to use already exists ones. The logs is cryptic or whatever. If you are already able to encrypt the data, you can write a custom beat to more minimal solution. I think this may be easier than writing logstash plugin but there is another challenge which is Golang. I don't know about logstash plugins but I wrote a [beat](https://github.com/hkulekci/filecountbeat) before. You can check excellent [beats documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/master/new-beat.html) to create one.

After create a beat for your system, you can forward your logs to logstash. There is a document about [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/config-filebeat-logstash.html). And also, you can check configuration of files in [this repo](https://github.com/hkulekci/elasticsearch-workshop) for a real example.